# can't find croissant dough; what can I substitute

Tags: substitutions

have recipe calling for croissant dough. can't find it at our groceries.  what can I substitute?

Comment: What are you trying to do with it? Please add the recipe or at least the intended use to get better answers. As it stands, your question is pretty unclear.

Comment: Yes, please tell us. Otherwise I'm inclined to say, "make croissant dough". As a matter of fact, I've never seen croissant dough for sale.

Comment: @Jolenealaska: In The Netherlands there's [this](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=croissantdeeg&FORM=HDRSC2), and I would assume in other countries too. You'll have to be pretty amazingly lenient and forgiving to call the end result a croissant, but it's for sale alright.

Comment: In the US there are a lot of recipes that use packaged Crescent Roll dough in a can. https://www.google.com/search?q=croissant+roll+dough&biw=1516&bih=904&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiP2dSh5eXJAhVR9mMKHR7EBdAQsAQIOA

Comment: @DebbieM. Crescent dough and croissant dough are very different things. They both are usually shaped somewhat similarly to bake. They are not interchangeable.

Comment: @Jolenealaska - True when making them yourself or buying the finished product. But when making something that pops out of a can http://justrw.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Pillsbury_02.jpg we may be talking about the same thing.

Comment: @DebbieM. Perhaps, but I won't make that (very large) leap without clarification.

Comment: I'd *love* to reopen this with clarification, but as-is as you can see, people are left guessing about your recipe and don't really know how best to help.

Answer (score 2):

You want what is called puff pastry dough. It is usually found near pie crusts at the store. It is sold flat or folded, but isn't sold in a roll like crescent dough. As comments have already mentioned, that is a different style of dough for a different style of pastry.

Comment: Those two aren't the same either. Croissant dough contains yeast, puff pastry does not.

Comment: @Jolenealaska Per the OP, croissant dough isn't available. Puff pastry may not have the same chewiness, but it does seem like the most reasonable substitute.

Comment: Puff pastry may very well be the best substitute. The OP may also be misreading, and is actually looking for crescent dough. Further, Willem van Rumpt has shown that there seems to be a product in the Netherlands called "croissant", packaged like crescents, but that looks like some kind of hybrid between crescent and croissant. I don't know which product is what the OP is looking for, so I really don't think the question is answerable until the OP clarifies.